# How to load ml model joblib dump file into celery task?

Tags: python, django, machine-learning, django-rest-framework

```
from transformers import pipeline
import joblib

cls = pipeline("automatic-speech-recognition", "facebook/wav2vec2-base-960h")
joblib.dump(cls, "model/wav2vec2-base-960h-model-joblib")
```

I used "facebook/wav2vec2-base-960h" to recognize/transcribe text from audio.

```
en_wav2vec2_model = joblib.load(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))+"/model/wav2vec2-base-960h-model-joblib")
```

using this way I load that model.

Now, This model loads properly when it is in a synchronized process. But when I use this model in the celery task it is hang. there is no error showing that the task is created but can not complete.